# Facebook server-side login in Nodejs while using react-router

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, react-router

Basically what I've got is this:

- Nodejs server running express, with this *get* path only (for now)

`app.get('*', (req, res) => {res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));`

- React-app with the following react-router routes (react-router-dom v4)

`
    import React from 'react';

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import Login from './components/Login';
import About from './components/About';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

const Routes = (props) => (
    <BrowserRouter {...props}>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

`

So now, I'm trying to do a Facebook server side login. How can I achieve that? FBdevelopers documentation isn't clear at all.

I've tryed using passport and I've got this code:

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/auth/login/facebook/return"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        return cb(err, user);
    }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.get('auth/login/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('auth/login/facebook/return',
     passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
     function(req, res) {
         res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
     }
);
```

But calling /auth/login/facebook/ gives me 404 not found since react-router has no route for it - obviously. Anyway, I can't understand how is it supposed to work since I can't find any client-side code other than an HTML anchor tag which hrefs to auth/login/facebook/. Is there a way to fix that or maybe can you suggest a better solution? Consider that I want to have the oauth flow server-side as much as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"FBdevelopers documentation isn't clear at all."_ - oh it very much is, in regard to what HTTPS redirects and requests need to happen. _"Anyway, I can't understand how is it supposed to work since I can't find any client-side code other than an HTML anchor tag which hrefs to auth/login/facebook/."_ - so? You're implementing the __server-side__ login flow here, so what extra client-side code do you expect to be involved here exactly?

Comment: Apart from that you need _something_ on the client to get it to request `/auth/login/facebook/`, the URL from where your server-side coding starts to trigger the login flow, there is no client-side coding involved at all here. (Considering that theoretically your users could type `http://yourappdomain/auth/login/ facebook/` into their browser address bar themselves, you can strike aforementioned "Apart from", and make that an absolute _there is no client-side coding whatsoever involved on your end of the server-side login flow._)